# Draw a line from the center of a circle to the edge:

Tags: circles, vector, axis

I'm trying to draw a circle with some radius vector drawn from the center of the circle to the edge (preferably at 45˚) and then a bunch of smaller circles – all on the xy-axis. I have the following code (I know it's probably overkill but I don't know if I want to have the tick marks later so I want to keep the axis environment (?).

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    xmin=-1,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=1,
    ticks = none,
    %xtick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    xticklabel = \empty,
    %ytick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    yticklabel = \empty,
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel=$x$
    ]
\draw (axis cs: 0, 0) circle [radius=2cm] (0,0);
\draw (axis cs: 0, 0) circle [radius=1.5cm];
\draw (axis cs: 0, 0) circle [radius=1cm];
\draw (axis cs: 0, 0) circle [radius=0.5cm];
\draw (axis cs: 0, 0) circle [radius=0cm];
\draw[-stealth] (axis cs: 0, 0) -- (25, 5) node[midway,below]{$r$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The light distribution at the $xy$-plane will look like this}
\end{figure}
```

However, any line I try to draw goes from the origin to the bottom left of the figure square (only in the 3rd quadrant). Is there any way I can make the vector go at 45˚ to the outer circle? 
Also, are there any other positions for the vector name besides either end or midpoint, I really don't want the other circles to get in the way of the 'r' and would like to clearly see it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! `pgfplots` rescales the axes individually unless you tell it otherwise by saying e.g. `axis equal`. Once you have done that you only need to draw a line to `(a,a)` with some `a` (or use polar coordinates and draw to `(45:r)` with some `r` in Ti*k*Z). I also add a plain Ti*k*Z version. Notice also that `pgfplots` rescales the units, so you need to be a bit careful where to use units or not. I hope the following helps you to achieve what you want to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    xmin=-2.5,
    xmax=2.5,
    ymin=-2.5,
    ymax=2.5,
    ticks = none,
    %xtick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    xticklabel = \empty,
    %ytick={-8, -6, ..., 8},
    yticklabel = \empty,
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel=$x$
    ]
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,0.5,...,2}    
 {\draw (0,0) circle [radius=#1];}
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (2.5,2.5) node[midway,below]{$r$};
 \draw[red,stealth-] ({-2/sqrt(2)},{-2/sqrt(2)}) --  ({-3/sqrt(2)},{-3/sqrt(2)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The light distribution at the $xy$-plane will look like this.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
 \draw[-stealth] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0) node[below]{$x$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5) node[left]{$y$};
 \foreach \X in {0,0.5,...,2}   
 {\draw (0,0) circle [radius=\X cm];}
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0) -- (45:{sqrt(2)}) node[midway,below]{$r$};
 \draw[red,stealth-] (-135:2) -- ++ (-135:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Ti\emph{k}Z version.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems adding \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} and then guessing and checking the coordinates to the outer circle did the trick! Graphing is a bit messy but I guess I'll get used to it!

Comment: @G.Poirier You're welcome. I actually changed the answer a bit because I had not taken into account that `cm` in an axis are true `cm` but this may not be what you want.